# Error:(20, 55) error: cannot find symbol class OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

New to Android programming

I am getting the cannot find symbol class error

```
buttonConvertMilesToKm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void Onclick(View v) {
                EditText textBoxMiles = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMiles);
                EditText textBoxKm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextKm);

                double vMiles = Double.valueOf(textBoxMiles.getText().toString());

                double vKm = vMiles / 0.62317;

                DecimalFormat formatVal = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                textBoxKm.setText(formatVal.format(vKm)) ;
            }
        });
```

I have this function where I am getting the above mentioned error can any one tell me

**Upadete**

changed `new OnClickListener()` to `new View.OnClickListener()`

**error**

`Error:(22, 78) error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener`
Thanks

Comment: there seems to be no error there. on which line?

Comment: @dionellorera this part `new OnClickListener()` . It was showing error so I changed to `new View.OnClickListener()` now getting new error abstract not override

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay i see the error now

```
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

check your public void Onclick it should be onClick(View v) not Onclick(View v)
check what is capitalized

Comment: @Dionellorero Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo on `public void Onclick(View v){}`, the 'c' shouldn't be lowercase. it should be: `public void onClick(View v) {}`